# Trouble with methods, and classes, and using the arrays form them

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, constructor

So basically, I have 2 classes (so far) "Seat" and "Theatre" and my main method.

I am to make a cinema booking system, and to do so I need to create a 'cinema' by using an array. However I want to be able to make as many of these cinemas as I want, and as I may add other variables such as (Time, movies, etc later) I thought I would make a "Theatre" class which contains an Array of Seats in its constructor, and then have a method which displays the array, however I'm not sure how to execute this.

Here is what I have so far"

Main Class:

```
public class CinemaSystem {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // Creating a cinema.

        Theatre cinema1 = new Theatre();


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Welcome to the Theatre Booking System. (QUIT to exit)"
                + "\nWould you like to purchase tickets or list available seats?"
                + "(/Purchase/List/Help)");
        String answer, answer2;

        answer = scan.nextLine();
        int count = 0;


        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("purchase")) {
            cinema1.DisplayTheatre(Seat 
            y[][]
          );


            } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("list")) {
        } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
            // Code for help
        } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            System.exit(-1);
        } else {
            do {
                System.out.print("Sorry, incorrect input please enter"
                        + " a valid input (Purchase/List/Help or QUIT to exit");
                answer = scan1.nextLine();
                count++;


                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("purchase")) {
                    // Code for purchase  
                } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("list")) {
                    // Code for list   
                } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
                    // Code for help
                } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                    System.exit(-1);
                } else if (count == 3) {
                    System.out.print("Are you stupid? Purchase/List/Help or Quit are your options. ... Terminating...");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            } while (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("purchase")
                    || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("list")
                    || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("help")
                    || !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"));




        }
    }
}
```

Seat Class:

```
public class Seat {


    public Seat() {
    }

    private String type;
    private boolean status;


    public String GetType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void SetType(String x) {

        type = x;
    }

    public boolean SetStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void GetStatus(boolean x) {
        status = x;
    }
}
```

Theatre Class:

```
public class Theatre{

    public Theatre() {
        Seat B = new Seat();
        Seat S = new Seat();
        Seat G = new Seat();



        Seat y[][] = {
            {B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B},
            {B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B},
            {B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B},
            {B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B},
            {B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B},
            {B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B, B},
            {B, B, B, B, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, B, B, B, B},
            {B, B, B, B, S, S, S, S, S, G, G, G, G, G, S, S, S, S, S, B, B, B, B},
            {B, B, B, B, S, S, S, S, S, G, G, G, G, G, S, S, S, S, S, B, B, B, B},
            {S, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, G, G, G, G, G, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, S},
            {S, S, S, S, S, S, S, G, G, G, G, G, G, G, G, G, S, S, S, S, S, S, S},
            {S, S, S, S, S, S, S, G, G, G, G, G, G, G, G, G, S, S, S, S, S, S, S},
            {S, S, S, S, S, S, S, G, G, G, G, G, G, G, G, G, S, S, S, S, S, S, S}
        };
    }

    public void DisplayTheatre(Seat x[][]) {
        for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < x[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(x[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

So since this doesn't work, I know I am going on about it the wrong way, how would I be able to print out the array that is in the Theatre classes' constructor?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance. ^^

Comment: We can understand properly intended codes. Writing so much of comments won't help if your code is not formatted properly.

Comment: I took out comments, and formatted using netbeans format thing, hopefully it is a little eaiser to read.

Comment: I had already done that. But it's ok that you did it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing three things wrong.

1. You are doing nothing to differentiate the objects, you call new `Seat()` for all three but you don't ever call `setType()` to change their values, so they would all print the same way. You might want to consider having a constructor `Seat(String type)` and load the value there.
2. Java naturally has the ability to turn all `Object`s into `String`s by the native method `Object.toString()` If you want to have your `System.out.print(x[row][col]);` print something other than the default `Object` output (this is almost always the case), you either need to explicitly call a method that returns the string you want (for example, `Seat.GetType()`, or create a method `public String toString()` in your seat class.
3. The variables in your constructor are all in local scope to the theater class. So after the Constructor finishes, they all disappear. Also, since in theater you seem to want to define the array as part of the theater object, you probably shouldn't be passing it as an argument, you should be just working with the field in the class. (Summary version: move the variable declarations outside the constructor)

Comment: Ok, I set values to the objects, I can't believe I didn't do that.

My main problem is, `cinema1.DisplayTheatre(Seat y[][])` line isn't working. I guess it is because when I instantiate the Theatre object, I can't use the Seat Array that is in the Theatre classes constructor in the method that I need to print the array. Have you any advice on how to fix that?

Comment: @user1719605: I added a third mistake that should solve your problem.

Comment: @user1719605: did that fix it? don't forget to check my answer as correct